# socket programming read-write with client-server

Tags: c, sockets

i am new to c program and socket, I am trying to get my concepts right before i start going in deeper. Below are my codes assuming my connection are all done and went into those methods where fd are the clientFd.

Server:

```
writeSomething (int fd)
{
    char str [200];

    while (readLine (fd, str)) 
    printf ("You have entered - %s\n", str);
}

readLine (int fd, char* str)
{
    int n;
    do /* Read characters until NULL or end-of-input */
    {
        n = read (fd, str, 1); /* Read one character */
    }
    while (n > 0 && *str++ != 0);       
    return (n > 0); /* Return false if end-of-input */
}
```

Client:

```
readSomething (int fd)
{
    print_intro();
    char input[200];
    do {
        printf ("Please enter something > ");
        fgets(input, 200, stdin);
        if (input == "end")
        {
            printf ("*** Thank you for using, have a nice day! ***");
            close (fd);
        } else {
            write (fd, input, strlen (input) + 1);
        }

    } while ( input == "")
}
```

My question:
1)Is that readLine() method really necessary or can i just read from client input and store into the variable 'str'? 
2) If yes how do i store the input into that 'str'?
3) How do make an infinite loop to prompt input until the user type 'end', my if else doesn't seem to be working?

Sorry for the trouble and thanks.

Comment: why there is no return type for functions?

Comment: @SouravGhosh sorry i am not very sure too, is my bad to follow blindly but somehow this code running fine for now

Comment: You need to call `write` in a loop - guess why.

Comment: I am confused, what are you trying to do? This has nothing to do with socket-programming. And if want to communicate between processes you need IPC-solution e.g. pipes. For communication between sockets you need to use send/sendto and recv/recvfrom depending which protocol type you using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is very confusing, however, the answers are.

1. `readLine()` is *actually* reading the input from the client using `read()` and storing that to `str`, yeah, byte by byte. What *else* you want to do as `read from client input`?
2. Not clear.
3. you cannot compare *string* using `==`. Use [`strcmp()`/ `strncmp()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strcmp).

Note:

1. Please add the return type of the functions. Don't rely on compiler for what task you're supposed to do.
2. while reading from `stdin`, `fgets()` reads and stores the last `\n`. Take care of that.